# Difference in server port and websocket port in node.js chat application

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, chat

I am trying to create a multi room chat application in node.js using socket.io and express. I am confused between use of server port and websocket port. I understand server port is used by the client to connect to server. But not sure about use of websocket port.

Thanks & Regards..

Answer (score 4):

webSockets can share the same port as your web server and this is a common configuration.  The reason this works is because of how a webSocket establishes a connection (all webSocket connections are initiated with an HTTP request).  It works like this:

1. Client makes an HTTP request to a web server with a header specifying that they want to "upgrade" to the webSocket protocol and sends a security-related header.
2. Web server sees the upgrade request and, if it has support enabled for webSocket connections, it will respond with a 101 request (switching protocols) and another security related header.
3. Client gets the accepted upgrade and both ends switch to the webSocket protocol and the original TCP socket that started out using the HTTP protocol is now using the webSocket protocol.

In this manner, the same port and webServer can be used for regular HTTP requests or webSocket connection requests.

For a chat application it is common to use a webSocket connection because it is a continuous connection that more easily allows the server to send information directly to the client which is often needed in a chat application.

To understand more about how a webSocket connection and server work, see this reference on MDN: [Writing WebSocket servers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) which shows the step by step process for initiating a webSocket connection.

Comment: @RobinSharma - Why did you remove the accepted answer?  Is your question not answered? If so, what are you still confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Server socket is used by server... that keeps listening to coming sockets request in a loop... and websocket sends a request to server socket and bound a connection between two devices...

Answer (score 0):

If you have / want to have web clients, [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is going to be required, because there is no access to 'regular' TCP (or UDP) sockets from browser-based JavaScript (and I assume you do not want Flash, SilverLight or Java Applets, in 2017). WebSocket is not special because of the port number, but it is special because of the protocol: a WebSocket connection starts as a regular HTTP connection, and [protocol upgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header) reconfigures it afterwards, it is designed for the browser-world, and even capable of traversing HTTP proxies. After establishing the connection, it provides a full-duplex, bi-directional message stream, very usable for chat applications.

And because of being a Web-thing, you could simply use port 80, if you are allowed to.